# For any argument form in the language of propositional logic, the tree for that argument

Tags: logic

> For any argument form in the language of propositional logic, the tree for that argument ...
>
> 1. always closes after a finite number of steps
> 2. can always be completed after a finite number of steps
> 3. can sometimes be closed only after an infinite number of steps
> 4. can sometimes be completed only after an infinite number of steps

Which of the option is true? 1, 2, 3 or 4? My attempt:

> My logic instructor told me infinite set of formulas are not allowed. He also told me infinite length formulas are not allowed.
>
> Therefore, I can only deal with finite sets of finite length formulas.
>
> There is no way to get an infinite step tree with a finite set of finite length formulas. (Not exactly sure about this)
>
> Therefore every tree must be able to be completed in a finite number of steps.

Option 2 is my answer.

Could someone check the reasoning for my argument?

Comment: If there's something unclear / wrong in my answer, how can I improve it?

Comment: im not sure what propositional logic and argument trees are but point 3 and 4 make no sense. how can anything be completed after a infinite amount of anything? it will never be completed because the infinite thing is like a wall nothing can go through. and if i had to chose between 1 and 2: for me 2 implies 1. maybe every tree ends in a finite amount of steps but is no completable? but if it is completable is certainly also ends in a finite amount of steps. But i dont know what this thread is about ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it surprisingly hard to find a good general reference about truth trees but here is one: http://pegasus.cc.ucf.edu/~stanlick/truthtrees.htm

A truth tree is a mechanical method of checking the validity of an argument in symbolic logic.  You start with the premises and the *negation* of the conclusion, and check to see if any possible interpretation does *not* lead to a contradiction.  If the negation of the conclusion is inconsistent with the premises under all interpretations, the argument is valid (by definition).

What makes a truth tree work is that every step in a truth tree decomposes a more complex branch into either one or two branches of a lesser order of complexity.  When a branch reaches the base level of complexity (a single statement, represented by a single letter or the negation of a single letter) it can be evaluated as either consistent with everything above it (open) or inconsistent (closed).

From the list of options, we can rule out #1 immediately, because some arguments (invalid ones) do not lead to closed trees.

To rule out number 3 and 4 we reason as follows:  Any finite argument (a finite set of finite premises and a finite conclusion) will have a finite order of complexity.  Since each decomposition of the tree reduces the complexity of a given branch, and adds at most two branches *of lesser orders of complexity*, only a finite amount of branches can be ever generated for any finite initial level of complexity, and all branches must eventually reach the base level of complexity in a finite number of steps.  Therefore every tree must complete in a finite amount of time.

Comment: Sounds like you might be able to turn any truth table into a truth *tree*.

Comment: Yes, it's really just an alternate way of presenting a truth table, with the advantage that you don't have to write out each row in full.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks fine to me.

You could make your third sentence more convincing by explaining the relation between the length of the formula (what would be a good measure?) and the size of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is correct. One could also use resolution. If there's a clause p∨¬q and another clause q∨r, one can conclude p∨r. If there's no such pair of clauses, the set is satisfiable. Otherwise one gets a smaller set of clauses and since it's finite one will finish after a finite number of steps (possibly arriving at a contradiction).